Можно ли помечать функции, использующие range алгоритмы, как noexcept?
Например, есть функция
auto toupper() /* noexcept */ {
  char str[] = "test";
  std::ranges::transform(str, std::begin(str), [](unsigned char c) -> char { return std::toupper(c); });
  return str;
}

Можно ли её пометить как noexcept, учитывая что сам std::ranges::transform не помечен так, но используемая в нём лямбда не должна выкидывать исключения?

@StanislavVolodarskiy так оно ж не в этой функции

Помечать noexcept можно практически все функции. Другое дело, есть ли в этом смысл. В этом примере функция гарантированно может выкидывать исключения при вызове копирующего конструктора строки при возврате. Если хотите получать вызов terminate в этом случае - то помечайте. @StanislavVolodarskiy Как раз наоборот - будет ли первое - неизвестно, может вызывающий переместит строку, а вот второе компилятор не удалит, так как на аргументы функции не распространяется NRVO.

Поменял пример, чтобы он касался только рендж алгоритмов, которые меня интересуют

А теперь он вообще не работает, так как возвращается адрес локальной переменной.

@user7860670 это ворнинг, неважно что не работает; смысл вопроса в использовании рендж алгоритма

@borg второй комментарий все еще в силе. Пометка noexcept не запрещает исключения, она заменяет разворот стека на terminate(). Если вы можете гарантировать что исключений тут не будет, помечайте. чисто формально даже инкремент итератора может вызвать исключение , но анный алгоритм от этого застрахован.
